# Search Closest value from multidimensional array without loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a large number of array with multidimensional array like:

I run a simple simulation for 5000 times by Years.
Example : for 70 years, I need to get 5000 data from loop.
so I have 70 array each have 5000 array.

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1787705
            [1] => 2019202
            [2] => 2293516
            [3] => 2525528
            [4] => 2771665
            ....
            [4999] => 82047445
        )

 [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1723480
            [1] => 1747268
            [2] => 1951914
            [3] => 2218200
             ........
            [4999] => 44638801
.......
[70] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1723480
            [1] => 1747268
            [2] => 1951914
            [3] => 2218200
             ........
            [4999] => 44638801
```

Now I want to search Closest or nearest value form a single value.

Like I need to search nearest value of 1747268 from that multidimensional array but not with loop, because it take already much time in previous loop, so How it is possible to find nearest value without loop.

Comment: is this data only available in these array's? Or is it stored in a database as well?

Comment: your data is sorted / not?

Comment: data is not sorted

Comment: It may have value large or small in any key

Comment: programs do not do magic, it follows a certain algorithm to manipulate data,
so unless a loop pass through your data at least once, you cant get that result

Comment: no solution for this, you have to compare each value.

Answer (score 0):

If your data isn't sorted, nor stored in a database, you'll have to do at least one loop. That's not the answer you asked for, but that's it.